# Remove specific storage from indexeddb

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, indexeddb

I was wondering if it's possible to remove a specific storage from and indexeddb or, in case this is not possible, how to clean all records inside a storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `delete(ID);` function in indexeddb

```
var request = store.delete(id);

  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    console.log("deleted")  
  };

  request.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("error--"+e);
  };
```

yes to delete entire store

```
 db.deleteObjectStore("storeName");
```

refer this for [more](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/)

Comment: thank you very much! I've also noticed there is the deleteObjectStore inside the db reference! thanks a lot!